# Combining two columns from different datasets into one table in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to take two columns from two different tables and combine them into one table, but not using any primary keys that are common between both. For example:

```
    val testDSArray : java.util.List[Integer] = new util.ArrayList[Integer]()
    testDSArray.add(4)
    testDSArray.add(7)
    testDSArray.add(10)

    val testDS: DataFrame = spark.createDataset(testDSArray)(Encoders.INT).toDF("col1")
    val testDS2: DataFrame = spark.createDataset(testDSArray)(Encoders.INT).toDF("col2")

    val columns = testDS.withColumn("col2", testDS2.col("col2"))
    columns.show(5)
```

I would expect this code to show something like:

```
---------------
| col1 | col2 |
---------------
|   4  |   4  |
|   7  |   7  |
|  10  |  10  |
---------------
```

However, the code above fails to run with error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: resolved attribute(s) col2#12 missing from col1#6 in operator !Project [col1#6, col2#12 AS col2#15];
```

Comment: you'd have to join the datasets

Comment: But joining without a key?

Comment: you can use get the rdd from each, zipWithIndex and then join or you can try  
adding a colimn with monotonicallyIncreasingId (from org.apache.spark.sql.functions)